# How to calculate accumulated vacation days in Excel based on days (and hours) worked per month?

Tags: excel, dynamic, calendar

TLDR: I need a way to track date values in a dynamic calendar and count the days I've worked on on a monthly base.

So I've made a dynamic calendar (in the 1904 Date system to enable negative time handling) to help me track days and hours worked in Excel that has some automatic features. I would now like to add a calculator to calculate the accumulation of vacation days based on the following conditions:

1. Days worked per month >= 14
   OR
2. The total hours worked per month >= 35

If one or both of these conditions are met I will receive 2 vacation days (2.5 after the 1st year of employment) and the accumulated vacation days should be shown in a single cell C7 (see picture for reference).

I know that I need to calculate the days that I've worked on on a monthly base and compare the result to the 1st condition (and the same for the worked hours and compare the result to the 2nd condition, but the solution for that is much the same as for the 1st condition). I've made my calendar in a way that I can't use fixed cells to do the calculation, as the length of the calendar is fixed to 53 full weeks and the dates change to accommodate the length according to the year in cell C2 i.e. January 1st will not always be in cell D17. Here are the first 10 rows of my dynamic calendar in Table Markdown format with the formulas as asked.

| Year | 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Quota | =SUM(J11:J375;'2022'!C2) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Hours per week | 37.5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Gross working days | =NETWORKDAYS(DATE(C2;1;1);DATE(C2;12;31);'1pyhapaivat'!B7:B21) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Net working days | =COUNTIF(H11:H381;">0") |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Vacation Accumulation |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Kilometers per day | 36 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Week No. | Date | Day | Start | end | Hours | Sum | Quota | Kilometers | Holidays | Note |  |
|  | =ISOWEEKNUM(D11) | =SEQUENCE(371;1;DATE($C$2;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($C$2;1;1);2)+1;1) | =D11 |  |  | =IF(M11="quota";-7,5/24;IF(G11>F11;IF((G11-F11)>(6/24);(G11-F11)-(0,5/24);(G11-F11));"")) | =SUMIF(H11:H15;">0") | =I11-COUNTA(G11:G15)*(($C$4/5)/24)-COUNTIF(M11:M15;"quota")*(($C$4/5)/24) | =COUNTA(F11:F15)*$C$8-(SUM(COUNTIF(M11:M15;"Remote");COUNTIF(M11:M15;"Office"))*$C$8) | =XLOOKUP(D11;_1pyhapaivat3[Start Date];_1pyhapaivat3[Subject];"") |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[A snippet of the dynamic calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPFAe.png)

I've tried combining the DATE and SUM functions with other functions like COUNTA, and COUNTIF. I've also tried using different LOOKUP functions but to no avail.

[The new dataset filtered by Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6EDA.png)
[And filtered again by Month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBjab.png)

Comment: What about sumif() or sumifs() ?

Comment: Some of the units in your question should be odd, if you work 35 hours in a month, you get 2 days of vacation? Please provide the input data in Table Markdown format, you can use the following tool: [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Please clarify too what are the input and output to consider in your question it is not clear to me the inputs from the screenshot

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I could probably use SUMIF or SUMIFS to do the calculations, but I need to track the dates in a dynamic calendar where the data set is going to shift on a year-to-year basis i.e. Jan 1st is not going to be in the same cell on every year.

Comment: But Jan 1st will be Jan 1st every year… so use the date as a criterion.

Comment: @DavidLeal Yes that is correct, but the 2 days of vacation I get are for the next year, so I cannot use them during the same year as I earn them (I get a total of 4 weeks of summer vacation this way). That, however is irrelevant regarding my question. I just need to track the dates on a monthly basis, as they shift on a year-to-year basis. If I can track the dates dynamically I believe I can get my vacation day calculator to work. 

I updated the question with the first 10 rows that show the formulas I use in the Table Markdown format.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes that is true, but I want to see If I've worked on Jan 1st based on the inputs to my calendar.

Comment: I figured out a solution that achieves what I wanted: first I use the FILTER function to filter out all the necessary data by year, then I use the FILTER function again on this new dataset to filter out each month into their own columns and SUM the total hours worked per month. Then I use an IF function to compare the sum to the 2nd value and if it is met, I print a "2" to the cell, and if it is not met I leave it empty (i.e. print "")

Not the most elegant solution to the problem but it seems to work flawlessly. Anyway thanks for your input.

I added snippets of the formulas to the post.